# Can the Neo4j Enterprise Edition Run on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, neo4j

There's really not much more to this question than the title, but I can't seem to find this answer anywhere.

I'm primarily interested in the backup capability of the Enterprise Edition and whether that is accessible when Neo4j is running on Heroku.

Comment: Are you referring to the Neo4j Heroku add-on? https://addons.heroku.com/neo4j

Comment: The edition of Neo4j running as the add-on is effectively Neo4j Enterprise. The current beta plan includes the ability to create backups. The public plans will add scheduled backups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Neo4j Heroku Add On (https://addons.heroku.com/neo4j) is managed by the Neo4j team. This is a developer instance, and it is currently free.

Production instances will be released in upcoming weeks, when Neo4j version 1.8 GA is released.

See https://groups.google.com/d/msg/neo4j/kidc4VeV_NA/spFwz2EeORgJ